# Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am in trouble. I have no idea how to solve the problem below. Could you give me some advice?

Now I have an error message.
RuntimeError at /
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id

☆the codes mentioned in the error message

block in 
_app_views_members_show_html_erb__17546xx63197x72440_70098x3x384700app/views/members/show.html.erb

When I put "15" following "limit" of the code below, I have the error but when I put "10", I have no error message... It happens only when I try to show localhost:3000/members/1.

☆members_show(view)

```
        <div class="message_area">
            <% posts_in_groups = GroupMessage.where(:member_id => params[:id]).order("created_at desc").limit(15) %>
            <%# posts_in_groups.each{|post_in_group| post_in_group }%>
           <div class="each_message">  
            <% posts_in_groups.each do |post_in_group|%>
                <a href="/groups/<%= post_in_group.group.id %>" ><%= image_tag post_in_group.group.imageurl, :width => '20', :height => '25' %><%= "(" + post_in_group.group.name + ")" %></a>
                <%= 'Page:' + post_in_group.page.to_s + '&' %><%= 'Line:' + post_in_group.line.to_s %>
                (<%= post_in_group.created_at.strftime'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M' %>)
              <div class="group_message">
                <p class="message_content"><a href="/group_messages/<%= post_in_group.id%>" ><%= post_in_group.content %></a></p>
              </div>
             <br>
            <% end %>
          </div><!--each message-- >   
        </div><!--message area-->
```

Comment: Not sure if you're already doing it, but have you considered using the [Facebook-Omniauth](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook) gem? You can also watch [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication) which talks about the specific thing you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr. Tamer. I already used it. To be precise, I made nomal login system and after that, I set up the Facebook login system. And there is a kind of confliction especially in [:login] and [:user_id].

Comment: Copy and paste the actual error along with whatever lines of code are mentioned in the error.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Tyler. I added error codes.

Comment: It looks like you've got some bad data.  The bad data has nil in it, and when you restrict the limit to 10, that bad data is not being loaded.  Can you verify that in all the rows you are trying to load are valid?

Comment: Just wanna say the way you are populating data like this inside your view is insane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type the Rail.logger line right after your loop starts.

```
<% posts_in_groups.each do |post_in_group|%>
<% Rails.logger.info "-----------------------#{post_in_group.group.id}" %>`
```

Then look at the console, it should show you what record it gets to before it errors out.

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr.fatfrog. I am not sure what to do after putting "Rails.logger.info" but I confirmed the content of  "post_in_group" and then it showed the 51st groupmessage. So I removed it and solved the problem.

Comment: That's great you figured it out.  Regarding the Rails.logger info - do you use the console while you develop?

Comment: Thank you Mr. fatfrog. I always use rails console but am not sure about exactly how to use it in this situation.